# Prompt user for input in WP CLI

Tags: wp-cli

I am missing some feature to prompt the user for input. In Laravel we have `$this->ask('What is your age')` (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#prompting-for-input)

I haven't been able to find any information on this online

Answer (score 2):

There's the [global parameter](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/references/config/)

```
--prompt[=<assoc>]
```

> Prompt the user to enter values for all command arguments, or a subset
> specified as comma-separated values.

### Example - Prompting two arguments

We can prompt post title and content of a given command with:

```
$ wp post create --prompt=post_title,post_content

4/30 [--post_content=<post_content>]: test
6/30 [--post_title=<post_title>]: test
wp post create --post_content='test' --post_title='test'
Success: Created post 14464.
```

where the resulting command is:

```
wp post create --post_content='test' --post_title='test'
```

### Example - Prompting all arguments

We can prompt all arguments of a given command with:

```
$ wp post create --prompt

1/30 [--post_author=<post_author>]:
2/30 [--post_date=<post_date>]:
3/30 [--post_date_gmt=<post_date_gmt>]:
4/30 [--post_content=<post_content>]: test
5/30 [--post_content_filtered=<post_content_filtered>]:
6/30 [--post_title=<post_title>]: test
7/30 [--post_excerpt=<post_excerpt>]:
8/30 [--post_status=<post_status>]:
9/30 [--post_type=<post_type>]:
10/30 [--comment_status=<comment_status>]:
11/30 [--ping_status=<ping_status>]:
12/30 [--post_password=<post_password>]:
13/30 [--post_name=<post_name>]:
14/30 [--from-post=<post_id>]:
15/30 [--to_ping=<to_ping>]:
16/30 [--pinged=<pinged>]:
17/30 [--post_modified=<post_modified>]:
18/30 [--post_modified_gmt=<post_modified_gmt>]:
19/30 [--post_parent=<post_parent>]:
20/30 [--menu_order=<menu_order>]:
21/30 [--post_mime_type=<post_mime_type>]:
22/30 [--guid=<guid>]:
23/30 [--post_category=<post_category>]:
24/30 [--tags_input=<tags_input>]:
25/30 [--tax_input=<tax_input>]:
26/30 [--meta_input=<meta_input>]:
27/30 [<file>]:
28/30 [--<field>:
29/30 [--edit] (Y/n):
30/30 [--porcelain] (Y/n):
wp post create --post_content='test' --post_title='test'
Success: Created post 14461.
```

where the resulting command is:

```
wp post create --post_content='test' --post_title='test'
```

### WP_CLI::confirm

Looking into [class-wp-cli.php](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/ae8be1523c0453ba43347d600c3f9caf8ff5bffc/php/class-wp-cli.php#L921) we also have the `y/n` confirmation:

```
 * # `wp db drop` asks for confirmation before dropping the database.
 *
 * WP_CLI::confirm( "Are you sure you want to drop the database?", $assoc_args );
```

that uses:

```
$answer = strtolower( trim( fgets( STDIN ) ) );
```

to get the user input answer.

We could use the construction of the `confirm` method as a base for more general user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any wp-cli utility either, but `readline` php function works just fine.

PHPStorm warns me that `ext-readline` must be enabled in order to use it, but it seems like something that is always enabled in cli environment